# C++11 - компиляторы

Tags: c++, c++11

Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли уже версии компиляторов для нового стандарта С++11?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сам недавно задался данным вопросом, когда не получилось применить *Range-Based for* в MSVC 10, поэтому нагуглил такую вот [табличку](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) . Надеюсь, что все данные, которые в ней содержатся полностью достоверны.

Comment: Жалко, что `concepts` убрали. Не знаю, чем они там руководствовались, когда решили зарезать такую концептуальную вещь *(извините за тавтологию :)*

Comment: Котик, мне стыдно признаться в невежестве, но не могли бы сказать, что такое эти концепты?

Comment: @mikillskegg

- Концепт - это возможность сказать, что вот какой-то конкретный шаблон имеет смысл только в том случае, если тип удовлетворяет некоторым свойствам, например, на нем задано отношение `<`.

- Если уж совсем утрировать, то концепты - это аналог продвинутой системы системных интерфейсов в языках `Java` / `C#`, позволяющие писать что-то вроде `template <typename T> where T : LessThanComparable`.

Comment: Tapadh leat

Comment: Рекомендую [выступление Страуструпа](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/A-Concept-Design-for-C-) о концептах, почему от них отказались в том виде, в котором их предлагали, и как именно они (скорее всего) будут реализованы в будущем.

Answer (score 0):

GCC с ключем -std=c++0x

Comment: Ну, полноценной поддержки пока что нет даже в вышедшем на днях gcc 4.7.1.